# Spark function rangeBetween until a condition met

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset in this format:

```
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+-----------------+
|     timestamp               |uuid                                |storyTopic  |Type             |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+-----------------+
|2019-04-15 11:21:03.362 -0400|9e0f3d00-cff7-3b76-89df-0d11c0addc91|TRY1        |Draft            |
|2019-04-15 11:21:06.547 -0400|null                                |TRY1        |Draft            |
|2019-04-15 11:21:06.617 -0400|e142e9bc-6587-34e3-9042-959b624f5   |Trial12345  |Original         |
|2019-04-15 11:21:08.196 -0400|null                                |TRY1        |Draft            |
|2019-04-15 11:21:22.855 -0400|null                                |TRY1        |Draft            |
|2019-04-15 11:23:36.108 -0400|null                                |TRY1        |Draft            |
|2019-04-15 11:23:36.139 -0400|null                                |TRY1        |Draft            |
|2019-04-15 11:23:50.311 -0400|null                                |TRY1        |Draft            |
|2019-04-15 15:21:08.196 -0400|null                                |TRY1        |Draft            |
|2019-04-15 15:21:12.617 -0400|e142e9bc-6587-34e3-9042-959b624f5   |Trial12345  |Original         |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+-----------------+
```

If the first row of the dataset has storyTopic as `TRY1`, 
1.find the row where the **timeDifference** is less than **5 seconds** 
 and 
2. **uuid is not null**

I tried to implement it in following way:

```
//create time difference column
df.withColumn("diff", functions.unix_timestamp(functions.col("timestamp")));
//create a window function for time-range
WindowSpec w = Window.orderBy("diff").rangeBetween(1L, 5L);
df.withColumn("Type", functions.when(
                (functions.rank().over(w)==1)
//checking if uuid is null
.and(functions.first("uuid").over(w).isNotNull()),
 functions.first("storyTopic").over(w)).otherwise("storyTopic");
```

What is happening is that it is ignoring the `uuid.isNotNull()` condition and getting the data from 2nd row not the 3rd row which fulfills both the condition.

How can I make sure that `functions.first()` picks up the row where uuid is not null?

Comment: Why not convert to Scala? - far easier than Java with Spark, H.

Comment: How would you do it in scala?

Comment: Example a little hard to follow

Comment: Hi there @Himanshu two questions: 1. with ` timeDifference is less than 5 seconds` you mean difference from the previous row? 2. could you provide the desired output?